# How to sort based on two fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a product model with `price` and `sale_price` fields.

I want to sort the records according to `price` in ascending order, but if a product has a `sale_price` value then it should be sorted according to `sale_price` not by `price`:

```
Product.id:1, Product.name:watch, Product.price:100, Product.sale_price:nil
Product.id:2, Product.name:Bag, Product.price:200, Product.sale_price:50
Product.id:3, Product.name:Shoes, Product.price:300, Product.sale_price:nil
```

I want this to be sorted as:

1. Bag
2. watch
3. Shoes

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including the links, and "[mcve]". We need to see evidence of your effort to solve this. Right now it looks like you didn't do anything and want us to write the code for you, which isn't what SO is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `coalesce`:

```
Product.order('coalesce(sale_price, price)')
```